# PHP 7.0 on Ubuntu 16 - pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_connect

Tags: pdo, ubuntu-16.04, php-7.0

I'm gettind this PDOException `could not find driver`

here is my `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` file

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_ftp.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

and when I run `php` in my server I get this warning `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_connect in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make sure that `/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqlnd.so` exists and my modules were been enabled by the `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available` directory, there were multiple `.ini` files, except for `mysqlnd.ini`

so I created it

```
sudo nano mysqlnd.ini
```

and put this content:

```
; configuration for php common module
; priority=10
extension=mysqlnd.so
```

restarted apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```